# exited, segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

The input for this problem is a first number that indicates how many cases will be input to be analyzed.

Input:

```
3
8 12
9 27
259 111
```

The first number means that there will be 3 cases. The next 3 lines are the cases. The program has to output the GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) of the 3 cases.

```
4
9
37
```

The code I wrote looks like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int gcd(int a, int b) {
   if (b == 0)
      return a;
   return gcd(b, a % b);

}

int main() {

   int N;

   std::cin >> N;

   int i = 0;

   std::vector<int> cards;

   while (i <= N) {
      i++;
      int F1, F2;
      std::cin >> F1 >> F2;
      cards[i] = gcd(F1, F2);
   }

   for (int j; j <= N; i++) {
      i++;
      std::cout << cards[i] << "\n";
   }
}
```

It reads the first integer (number of test cases), runs the loop once (reads one test case) and stops running. The terminal outputs `exited, segmentation fault`. What is the problem?

Comment: There are multiple issues. You are trying to code in C++ with a C style. Read your book again, use the debugger.

Comment: Your last for loop contains a typo.

Comment: Remember that C arrays start at index 0.  Dont' skip the 0th entry and loops that use `<=` are almost always not correct.

Comment: Your vector has zero length. Yes it represents a dynamic array, but you still need to set its size, using `cards.resize(N)` or likewise (also remember that vector indices are zero based). Also your loops looks strange; the common idiom to iterate N times is `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)`.

Comment: why are you tagging C++11, 14, 17?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis what do you mean by C style?

Comment: The variable `j` in the last `for` loop is never initialized.  You are also incrementing the `i` variable twice in the `for` loop (once in the `for` statement, the next following it).  The `loop` never changes the variable `j`.

Comment: You'll get a run-time error because the `cards` vector is empty when you declare it, so `cards[i]` is not defined.  You may want to use `cards.push_back(gcd(F1, F2));`.

Comment: In your last `for` loop, you may want to change the statement to: `for (int j = 0; j < cards.size(); ++j)`.

Comment: `for (int j; j <= N; i++)` (A) What is the purpose of `j` if you're incrementing `i`? (B) What do you think happens when the uninitialised `j` is read? (C) Why do you then increment `i` again inside the loop body? This code is illustrative of how you need to step back a bit and learn what the code you're writing actually does before just writing more and more of it

Answer (score 1):

In your code there are some problem, first of all you haven't setted the size of the vector, that result like it has 0 lenght.

Another error are the loops;
In fact in the firts one you add 1 to i before you do all the other operation, and in this way you'll start to insert from te second component of the vector (vector start his indexing at 0).

Also in the second loop there are some problems, for example you declare a variable j that it is totally usless becouse in the folowing operations you still use i (that is setted at the end value of the previous loop, the while one).

Try to correct this things and understand it and in this way you'll understand also the reason of your error, that is pretty common in c++.

I hope that i've helped you a bit :)